# How to read ApplePencil pressure data outside an UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-pencil

Is it possible to read the pressure data from ApplePencil outside an UIView? For example on the frame of an iPad?

I have stumbled across [this project](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2015/11/pencilscale-using-apple-pencil-with.html), where the ApplePencil was used as electronic scale. But in this project the tip of the pencil still needs to be on the iPad display inside an UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for an Apple Pencil to draw outside of a device screen.

However there exist some smart pens with iOS SDKs wich you can use to draw and get the data via bluetooth.
The Neo smartpen is just one example: https://github.com/NeoSmartpen/IOS-SDK2.0

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand that there is no way of telling the location of the Apple Pencil outside of the display area but I have read that the pressure information transfers via bluetooth, therefore I thought it should be possible to get this data without the screen?